# Pull an IP from the landing page and compare to known users

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a working sql query that will give an accurate FLAG for a known or unknown IP address in our database upon hitting our landing page. I use this

```
// get the IP of the user on this landing page
$ip_address=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; 
echo $ip_address. ' ip address<br/>';

// see if we know this user..
$search_first="SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(ip_address)) FROM `qb_sessions` WHERE `ip_address` = '$ip_address' ";
$has_ips = mysql_query($search_first);
$has_ip = mysql_num_rows($has_ips);
echo $has_ip. ' has IP<br/>'; // should show count in table
```

Using this snippet does not provide the result that I need.  If the table is empty, (no match to this IP), I still get a '1' as the echo of $has_ip. I really need '0' if there is no match, and anything '&gt 1' if this IP has been recorded in `qb_sessions` table before. The purpose of this snippet is to identify a new, non-registered hit on this landing page and later to redirect them to another page, like join a newsletter, get a discount coupon, etc.

I have tried various combinations of the sql to no avail, including escaping the (') $ip_address quotes.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: By the way, you should strongly consider switching to `mysqli` or `PDO` functions: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php (`mysql_query` has been deprecated for a while).

Comment: Thank you everyone !!.. Yes, the COUNT() was throwing it off, which I figured out before looking back here...  _(As for @Rajdeep Paul sidenote:... I am aware, but must work with what is on this site right now... transitions are underway in development servers.. but this item needs to be **immediately live according to my superiors**.)_

Comment: @SteveK Please *green ticked* one of the answers as *accepted* answer to close the question, otherwise this question will be floating around SO as *open* question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ... If the table is empty, (no match to this IP), I still get a '1' as the echo of `$has_ip`.

That's because of MySQL's `COUNT()` function. Whether the table contains 1 row or n rows `SELECT COUNT(...) ...` will still return **exactly one row** containing a number which shows the number of rows returned from the `SELECT` query.

Since you're using PHP's `mysql_num_rows()` function anyway to count number of rows, drop `COUNT()` from your `SELECT` query.

```
$search_first="SELECT DISTINCT(ip_address) FROM `qb_sessions` ...
```

---

**Sidenote:** Don't use `mysql_*` functions, they are deprecated as of PHP 5.5 and are removed altogether in PHP 7.0. Use [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`pdo`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead. [**And this is why you shouldn't use `mysql_*` functions**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(ip_address))
```

This is *always* going to return a row.  Exactly one row.  Containing exactly one number.  That number might be a zero, but there will be a row in the result containing that number.

```
mysql_num_rows($has_ips)
```

This will always be 1, because the above query will always return one row.

Instead of counting the returned rows, examine the already-counted returned value.  Something like this:

```
$has_ips = mysql_query($search_first);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($has_ips);
$has_ip = $row[0];
echo $has_ip. ' has IP<br/>';
```

(I *think* that's how a result would be fetched, it's been a while since I've written PHP code.  But the idea is straightforward enough, you want the first (only) element of the first (only) returned row.)

Answer (score 0):

Should be binding your parameters via PDO.

Here is an alternative way, here I simply check if any results have been returned.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM qb_sessions WHERE ip_address=:ip_address");
$stmt->bindParam(':ip_address', $ip_address);
$ip_address = "73.85.207.17"; // example ip
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
echo (count($result) > 0) ? 'IP found' : 'IP NOT found';
```